# The torch button is missing. How do I get it back?

Tags: camera-flash, quick-settings

I've always had a torch icon in the quick settings tray, for example (from another phone):

[image]

However mine now looks like this:

[image]

I think it happened after I tried taking a video with the stock camera app (Nexus 5X).

As a workaround I can turn it on by enabling the flash when about to record a video, but this is really inconvenient. I'd like to be able to switch it on without unlocking the phone.

Comment: @beeshyams no, not rooted. I'm using the Nova launcher if that could affect anything.

Comment: Enable [system UI Tuner](http://m.androidcentral.com/inside-marshmallow-system-ui-tuner) . Once enabled, you will find it at bottom of settings options. Click that and from 3 button menu, there if an option for *reset* - see if that helps bring back *torch*

Comment: There's also an  *add tile* option. That can also help

Comment: @beeshyams Torch is there. Unfortunately reset doesn't bring it back in the actual menu. Neither does deleting and re-adding the torch.

Comment: If you just want a shortcut, instead of getting back the lost icon there, Power Toggles app may be a solution for you https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.painless.pc&hl=en

Comment: @Madushan Thanks, but I really like being able to turn the torch on without having to unlock the phone.

Comment: Power Toggles does provide a sticky notification (kinda like the old Samsung UI) which you can configure to do that.

Comment: @jozxyqk: Have you tried a reboot? Occasionally something will get wedged after you use the camera app, and block anything else from using the camera hardware, which includes the flash/torch.

Comment: @Josh Yes, I tried as soon as I noticed, but it didn't change anything. Just rebooted again now and it back! Thanks very much :)